# How to start service in docker container at start up

Tags: docker, centos, containers, dockerfile, opentsdb

I am trying to setup docker image for OpenTSDB with following docker file

```
FROM centos:6.7
MAINTAINER http://www.centos.org

RUN yum -y update && yum clean all
RUN yum -y install httpd && yum clean all

RUN yum -y install java-1.7.0-openjdk
RUN yum -y install gnuplot
RUN yum install -y https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/releases/download/v2.2.0/opentsdb-2.2.0.noarch.rpm
RUN sed -i '/^#tsd.storage.hbase.zk_basedir*/c\tsd.storage.hbase.zk_basedir = \/hbase-unsecure' /etc/opentsdb/opentsdb.conf
RUN sed -i '/^#tsd.storage.hbase.zk_quorum*/c\tsd.storage.hbase.zk_quorum = 10.8.18.14:2181,10.8.18.15:2181,10.8.18.17:2181' /etc/opentsdb/opentsdb.conf
RUN echo 'tsd.storage.fix_duplicates = true' >> /etc/opentsdb/opentsdb.conf
RUN echo 'tsd.http.request.cors_domains = *' >> /etc/opentsdb/opentsdb.conf
EXPOSE 4242
CMD service opentsdb start && tail -F /var/log/opentsdb/opentsdb.log
```

Last CMD is to start the opentsdb as a service, but it doesn't works.

Dont know what I am missing here, Can someone help with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should launch your docker process in the foreground, do not rely on init, upstart, or other OS service controllers to run your command. I'm not familiar with opentsdb, but it appears they have the following to start their process in the foreground:

```
CMD tsdb tsd
```